# Fastest way to compare two strings with dynamic white space?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, performance

I have two strings `bigstring` and `smallstring`, and each string is a paragraph of words. However in between each word is a bunch of whitespace (`\s` in regex) characters of random length.

So for example `bigstring` could be like `hello   world`. And this goes for `smallstring` too.

What I want to be able to do is, check if `smallstring` is a substring of `bigstring` (word for word) where the `\s+` part of it is considered the same, and **case insensitively**. So for example if

`bigstring = "hello   \t\r\n  world \n foobar"`

`smallstring = "HELLO \t world"`

then `smallstring` is a substring of `bigstring`.

`bigstring = "hello   \t\r\n  world \n foobar"`

`smallstring = "HEL"`

This is not a substring (word for word), because there is no word called `hel` in `bigstring`.

`bigstring = "the   \t\r\n  nest"`

`smallstring = "then \n est"`

This is also not a substring (word for word).

One method is to tokenize both strings into arrays, so break up the stuff between `\s+` into tokens, and the `\s+` is the delimiters. Then literally check if one array is contained in the other array in order and consecutively with case insensitively.

However in this case, I need speed to be the priority, as it should be the fastest way.

Does anyone know a way to check this?

I was perhaps thinking of a way to check these strings as you loop through both, character by character, but not sure how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: One option you could try would be creating a regex dynamically out of `smallstring` by splitting it on `/\s+/`, escaping each component, and joining it back together with `"\\s+"`, then running that regex on `bigstring`.

Comment: There may be some smarter algorithm, but the simple algorithm is to create a StringBuilder instance to build up, character by character (one for each string) in a for loop, and use a state variable to convert any series of whitespace to one space, adn then at the end you can just to a normal substring. So basically replacing all whitespaces with one single whitespace is the only hard part.

Comment: you could do replace (/\s/+, " "), but i feel like there is a faster way if you do everything in 1 loop.

Comment: Is it OK to assume that all whitespace could be replaced by a single space?

Comment: I think it is safe to assume replacing consecutively whitespace to 1 is ok, but then it creates multilple loops. I was thinking of doing everything in 1 loop at the same time, if possible.

Comment: if smallstring is user input, fastest will probably be to generate lookup object/Map with the words or characters in bigstring before the search

Comment: Execution time is heavily related to memory aloc so I quess that fastest will be some combination of indexOf and for loop.. RegExp is way of shortest code but in most cases definitely not fastest..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where this ranks on speed, but does this achieve your goal (now **edited** for edge case of 'impl' vs. 'mpl', by adding leading space)

```
var isSubstring = function(bigstring, smallstring) {
  bigstring = " " + bigstring.replace(/\s+/g, " ").toLowerCase() + " "
  smallstring = " " + smallstring.replace(/\s+/g, " ").toLowerCase() + " "
  return(bigstring.indexOf(smallstring) >= 0)
}
```

Adding a trailing (and, now, leading) space covers the case where smallstring is a single word fragment ('hel' vs. 'hello' and 'impl' vs. 'mpl' in your example above and in comments below)

Use cases:

```
bigstring = "hello   \t\r\n  world \n foobar"
smallstring = "HELLO \t world"
console.log(isSubstring(bigstring, smallstring))
//evaluates to true

bigstring = "hello   \t\r\n  world \n foobar"
smallstring = "HEL"
console.log(isSubstring(bigstring, smallstring))
// evaluates to false

bigstring = "impl"
smallstring = "mpl"
console.log(isSubstring(bigstring, smallstring))
// evaluates to false
```

Comment: That's definitely the 'best' answer Eric, except for everybody i know hates REGEX and i avoid it at all cost. :)

Comment: @ClayFerguson Regexes are beautiful little puzzles sent by God to earth to bring joy and brevity to our otherwise dull lives.  But ok.

Comment: This does seem like it would work, but just makes too many full string loops. I think I am looking for a much more optimized version that loops through both strings at most one, and does everything it needs to check for in that 1 loop.

Comment: because these strings can be really really big.

Comment: @Omega, the regex shouldn't be doing unnecessary looping. Frankly Erics solution should definitely be accepted, unless there's a typo in it. It's correct, and the best way (short of any typos). I'm not good with REGEX but i know what he posted is the best way.

However there will be some inflection point where if you have a BIG ENOUGH string it will end up being better to not REGEX it but just build two new strings into StringBuilder (converting spaces to one space), but i don't know how big is big enough to make REGEX bog down performancewise.

Comment: @ClayFerguson: You know it’s the best way because…?

Comment: Actually this fails on the case like this `impl ` and you check `mpl` as substring. I'ts because there was no enforced white space on the left side. But that also might mess up the algorithm implementation.

Comment: @omega: Performance differences here will probably be more about creating new strings and less about looping multiple times (which is somewhat close to doing more things per loop iteration). You should benchmark it and see if it’s fast enough for your purposes.

Comment: @Ryan I did post a caveat (end of paragraph) saying REGEX "could" get bogged down. But basically this is a problem of "how do i convert all whitespaces in a string to a single space each". And that just screams REGEX if regex can do it. Again if it's a gigabyte string, you might even be better of writing to a FILE the 'single-space' versions, etc.

Comment: I think you are right about speed, this definitely does run fast. But i think i identified an issue in a few comments above.

Comment: @Omega your note about that "Impl " edge case is precisely why i avoid REGEX unless performance is CRITICAL and i have PLENTY of time to vet and test the regex string, which usually takes more time than it's worth, when a simple loop conveys your intent much more clearly. REGEX is concise and effecient usually, but at the price of being 'undecipherable to mere mortals'

Comment: @omega i made an edit (leading white space) to capture your edge case of impl and mpl.  Also turned it into a function to facilitate testing the use cases.  It would be interesting to benchmark against other approaches.  It may be a challenge to beat the regex engine which was Written By Pros™

Answer (score 1):

RegExp is definitely not the fastest, but you can search the big string with a `RegExp` generated from the small string:

```js
bigstring = "hello   \t\r\n  world \n foobar"

smallstring = "HELLO \t world"

r = new RegExp( '\\b' + smallstring.replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+') + '\\b', 'i' )

console.log( r.test(bigstring), r ) // true /\bHELLO\s+world\b/i
```

A faster case-insensitive string search would most likely use [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and/or some kind of a word/token lookup structure, as for example https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search seems to use.

Answer (score 0):

Let `F(a)` will return unified version of string `a`. By unified I mean that all consecutive space characters will be replaced by a single space and all letters will be moved to lower case. This function can be calculated in linear time - `O(|a|)`.

In this case you need to check if `F(smallstring)` is substring of `F(bigstring)`. To handle this quickly you can use some standard algo like [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).